# SRVE0255E A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /app-name has not been defined. but i have defined the action class in struts-config.xml

Tags: java, struts, jsp-tags

I have been adding multilanguage option in jsp page using hyperlink.

```
"<html:link page="/Locale.do?method=chinese">Chinese</html:link> . "
```

but i'm getting **SRVE0255E** error A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /app-name/Locale.do has not been defined. when i clicking the hyper link for chinese language conversion . the action class(Locale.do) has been defined in struts-config.xml file

The code snippet in struts-config.xml is:

```
<action path="/Locale" parameter="method"  type="com.tdt.struts.multilanguage.LanguageSelectAction"
    name="DetailForm" >
    <forward name="success" path="jsp/header.jsp" />
    </action>
```

Comment: Please [review Stack Overflow's guide to asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as currently your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: The issue isn't the action configuration but the app and/or server.

Comment: Hi Dave, Can u pls explain briefly about what need to be done in app or server.TIA